# How Can i Make Fps Controller Rotate and face a target

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm developing my first game so am a bit new to Unity. So my problem is am trying to rotate the Fps Controller to face a target by the push of a button. I managed to rotate the camera alone by attaching this code to it but only the camera rotates so it completely messes up the walking

```
public class PlayerRotate : MonoBehaviour {

     public Transform target;

     void Update(){
         if(Input.GetKeyDown("r")){
             print ("Rotate");
             transform.LookAt(target.position);
         }
     } 
 }
```

I also tried attaching the same script to the Fps Controller but nothing happens. Anyone's help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Google FPS Controller Script... http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/700918/how-to-get-my-camera-to-follow-first-person-pov-in.html

Answer (score 0):

FPSCaracterController rotation is driven by the MouseLook.cs script that incorporates its asset.
If you open it you will see the function that controls the rotation:

```
public void LookRotation(Transform character, Transform camera)
```

This method modifies the value of the rotation directly with the value of the mouse without any intermediate operation. So if you want to change the rotation of the FPController you need to modify this method (or this class)

For example, I have made this modification makes the FPController rotate 180 degrees every time the user presses the "U" key:

```
public void LookRotation(Transform character, Transform camera)
{
     float yRot = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Mouse X") * XSensitivity;
     float xRot = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * YSensitivity;

        m_CharacterTargetRot *= Quaternion.Euler(0f, yRot, 0f);
        m_CameraTargetRot *= Quaternion.Euler(-xRot, 0f, 0f);

        if (ORPargaModification)
        {
            if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.U))
            {
                Debug.Log("U pressed");
                m_CharacterTargetRot *= Quaternion.Euler(0f, 180, 0f);
            }
            character.localRotation = m_CharacterTargetRot;
            camera.localRotation = m_CameraTargetRot;

        }
        else
        {
            if (clampVerticalRotation)
            m_CameraTargetRot = ClampRotationAroundXAxis(m_CameraTargetRot);

            if (smooth)
            {
                character.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(character.localRotation, m_CharacterTargetRot,
                    smoothTime * Time.deltaTime);
                camera.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(camera.localRotation, m_CameraTargetRot,
                    smoothTime * Time.deltaTime);
            }
            else
            {
                character.localRotation = m_CharacterTargetRot;
                camera.localRotation = m_CameraTargetRot;
            }

        }

        UpdateCursorLock();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply man, I'll definitely give it a try